# Proper way to pass LiveData in ViewModel taken from suspended Repository

Tags: kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I'm wrapping my head around Kotlin coroutines and LiveData. I want to do really basic use case where ViewModel returns LiveData taken from Repository suspended function, which returns LiveData as well.

Repository function signature:

```
suspend fun getAll() : LiveData<List<Mountain>>
```

It can't simply do that:

```
fun getMountains() : LiveData<List<Mountain>> {
  return mountainsRepository.getAll()
}
```

because the compiler states that suspend function should be called from coroutine or another suspend function. 
I came up with 2 ugly solutions, but I know they aren't elegant:

**1 Solution with runBlocking**

```
fun getMountains() : LiveData<List<Mountain>> = runBlocking { mountainsRepository.getAll() }
```

**2 Solution with nullable LiveData**

```
fun getMountains() : LiveData<List<Mountain>>?{
    var mountains : LiveData<List<Mountain>>? = null
    viewModelScope.launch{
        mountains = mountainsRepository.getAll()
    }
    return mountains
}
```

How can I do this properly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a [liveData builder](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines#livedata) that can call suspend functions in its body.
So your view model function can look like

```
fun getMountains() = liveData {
   emit(mountainsRepository.getAll()) 
}
```

make sure you are using at least

```
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.2.0"
```

And as Lena mentioned - removing `suspend` from your repository `getAll()` function do not make it blocking.

Having

```
fun getAll() : LiveData<List<Mountain>>
```

in your repo, and

```
fun getMountains() = mountainsRepository.getAll()
```

in your view model, could be a better way to achieve the same goal

Comment: Ok, but my repo function is `suspend`, because it also invokes web API function with is `suspend` too, so I can't remove this keyword :(

Comment: if you repo function returns ``List<Mountain>`` you can just simply post it to liveData or user ``liveData`` builder. If you are using both suspend and livedata in one function signature you are just handling async operation twice and making excess headache for yourself

Answer (score 0):

remove the suspend keyword from `suspend fun getAll() : LiveData<List<Mountain>>`

LiveData in Room is already asynchronious and it will work just fine in the background, if you are using Room to get your live data.

[Room, Coroutines, LiveData](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5)

Comment: I can't do that, becuase my repository calls API service suspended function  ```@GET("mountains")
    suspend fun getAll(): Response<List<MountainBrief>>```